# Adding python to eclipse

Tags: eclipse, pydev

After installing eclipse, I used *help* -> *install new software*, I added once, http://pydev.org/nightly, and the other time, http://pydev.org/updates. But nothing appeared in *name* of *install* window. Could you please guide me?

[image]

Comment: Your window is to small to see the selectable elements. It should be above the "Select All" button. Try to enlarge the view a bit.

Comment: yes u are rigth. thanks :)